# Notion of base2-logarithm in RC6 specification

Tags: implementation, rc6

I was reading [this paper on RC6](https://people.csail.mit.edu/rivest/pubs/RRSY98.pdf) and formally, the algorithm is defined for an arbitrary word size $w$, even though only $w=32$ was considered for the AES submission. Now the paper explicitly mentions the choice $w=24$, among others. Later on in the paper, it says:

> *"The base-two logarithm of $w$ will be denoted by $\operatorname{lg}w$."*

As part of the encryption routine, the following step is performed:
$$
t = (B\times(2B+1)) \lll \operatorname{lg} w
$$
This makes perfect sense for $w=32$ as $32$ is a power of two and $\operatorname{lg} w$ will be an integer, by which you can rotate another integer. However, for $w=24$, this formally asks me to rotate the value by approximately $4.584962500721156$ bits, which I find rather puzzling.

My question is: What is the correct interpretation of $\operatorname{lg} w$ for implementations of RC6 that allow other values for $w$, specifically when $w$ is *not* a power of two?

Comment: https://github.com/TakLun/RC6/blob/master/RC6/RC6.cpp#L7

Comment: @kelalaka this is definitely one way to do it, but I was hoping there was an "official" reference for how this should be handled.

Comment: It is more about least-significant fraction bit vs least-significant  bit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[From RC6 and RC5 Test Vectors For Multiple Block Sizes](https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-krovetz-rc6-rc5-vectors-00.html) (draft-krovetz-rc6-rc5-vectors-00)

```
/* Calculate floor(base-2 log of x) for any x>0.                   */
static int lg2(int x) {
    int ans=0;
    for ( ; x!=1; x>>=1)
        ans++;
    return ans;
}
```

So the return is the LSB of the integer part;

`log_w = (unsigned int)log2(w);`

Test it [here](https://onlinegdb.com/tCvERPHX6),

Comment: There should be [NIST test values](http://www-08.nist.gov/encryption/aes/round1/testvals/rc6-vals.zip), however, they are missing even in the [web.archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20060625224909/http://www-08.nist.gov/encryption/aes/round1/testvals/rc6-vals.zip)

Comment: Thank you! This is perfect.

Comment: Note that [Schneier codes](https://www.schneier.com/books/applied-cryptography-source) only includes `5` as hard coded $log_2$.